# How to sort list in SwiftUI using JSON

Tags: swiftui

I have a list that I need to sort by "popularity" (more popular to less popular), this value comes from a JSON API. Is there a Sort function by given value in SwiftUI?

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "The design of every day things",
    "autor": "Don Norman",
    "disponibilidad": true,
    "popularidad": 70,
    "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410RTQezHYL._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "100 años de soledad",
    "autor": "Garcia Marquez",
    "disponibilidad": false,
    "popularidad": 43,
    "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51egIZUl88L._SX336_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
}
]
```

There's more to it, that's just a piece of it.
Popularity is `popularidad`.

This is currently my list:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(booksVM.books) { book in
                    HStack {
                        Text(book.nombre)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Text(book.autor)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.padding(.leading, 5)
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Bienvenido a la librería flux")
    .onAppear(perform: self.booksVM.fetchBooks)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if more code is needed to understand this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `.sorted` to sort your array.

Here is a simple example using your data. This will work if you try it in a playground.

```swift
let data = """
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "The design of every day things",
        "autor": "Don Norman",
        "disponibilidad": true,
        "popularidad": 70,
        "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/410RTQezHYL._SX326_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "100 años de soledad",
        "autor": "Garcia Marquez",
        "disponibilidad": false,
        "popularidad": 43,
        "imagen": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51egIZUl88L._SX336_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!


struct Book: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let popularidad: Int
    let nombre: String
    let autor: String
    let disponibilidad: Bool
    let imagen: String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let books = try decoder.decode([Book].self, from: data)

let result = books.sorted {
    $0.popularidad > $1.popularidad
}

print(result)
```

You would just have to perform your sort before you use the array of books in the `ForEach`

So all you have to do is the following which will sort your array of `Book` objects.

```
ForEach(booksVM.books.sorted { $0.popularidad > $1.popularidad}) { book in
```

Comment: But then I would have to hardcode each book. There are more books in the JSON. Probably should've said that.

Comment: You should be using `Codable` to convert your json into an array of `Book` objects. I have updated the example so that you can see how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using Codable. So all I needed was the ForEach line. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is `booksVM.books...`?

Comment: `booksVM` is an `ObservedObject` with an `@Published` property of `books`, where `books` is `[Book]`.

Comment: WONDERFUL! TY SO MUCH!
`List (results.sorted {$0.duration < $1.duration}, id:\.id) ` right in the UI works perfectly for me. I was making it so difficult when it is so simple. if SO had reddit-gold I'd give you some.