# Auto incrementing and sorting list SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to add a leaderboard to my application, I have created a list and it is currently getting the information from my FireStore database using this view model

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class LeaderboardViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var leaders = [Leader]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchLeaderboard() {
    db.collection("Leaderboard").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No Leaderboards")
            return
        }
        
        self.leaders = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Leader in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let score = data["score"] as? String ?? ""
            return Leader(name: name, score: score)
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is my model file

```
import Foundation

struct Leader: Identifiable, Codable {
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var name: String
var score: String
}
```

And it is displaying in a list using this

```
        NavigationView {
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            
            List(viewModel.leaders) { leader in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(leader.score) \(leader.name)")

                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Leaderboard")
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchLeaderboard()
        }
    }
```

However, I would like it to have a number next to each score indicating which position they are and also sort them into the positions based on their score.

Comment: Sounds like a good goal. What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort list in SwiftUI using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733155/how-to-sort-list-in-swiftui-using-json)

Comment: Check the accepted answer on the linked question: you can sort your entries when you are passing the array to the list. Side note: it's more efficient to have `var id: UUID = UUID()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here; displaying the index and then sorting by score.

If you want to display the index for each entry use `indicies` or `indexed`

Try this

```
List(leaders.indices, id: \.self) { index in
   Text("#\(index):  \(self.leaders[index].score) \(self.leaders[index].name)")
}
```

or this

```
List(leaders.indexed(), id: \.1.self) { index, leader in
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("\(idx):  \(leader.score) \(leader.name)")
   }
}
```

As far as sorting goes, there are a number of options; you could let Firebase do the sorting for you and present data to your app sorted *or* you could load the data into an array and sort in code.

Sorting (ordering) data is pretty well covered in the Firestore documentation here [Order and Limit Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) if you want Firestore to handle it but in a nutshell

```
db.collection("leaders").order(by: "score").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

Sorting in code would be done using standard Swift sorting methods.

If the dataset is small, sorting is code is fine - however, datasets can grow so offloading that processing to the Firebase servers is often a best practice.